# Is there any Shell script to replace values of File1.dat to file2.dat with out changing the file format for each line

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a `file1.dat` and a `file2.dat` containing values. I want to replace the values of the `file2.dat` with the `file1.dat` in the first column by changing the file format and data.

I tried this awk command, but problem is its changing the file format and the entire first column is getting changed.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}{$1=a[FNR]}1' file1.dat file2.dat > result.dat
```

File1.dat (input):

```
A123456789      1      C      HIE   1   48.343 23.545 32.02 1.00 0.00        H
A875678235      3      C      PHE   1   48.343 23.545 32.02 1.00 0.00        C
A907654234      4      N      ALA   1   48.343 23.545 32.02 1.00 0.00        N
A907863544      5      B      VAL   1   48.343 23.545 32.02 1.00 0.00        B
```

File2.dat (input):

```
987654321
567890123
098765432
890765348
```

Desired output:

```
A987654321      1       C     HIE   1  48.343 23.545 32.02 1.00 0.00         H
A567890123      3       C     PHE   1  48.343 23.545 32.02 1.00 0.00         C
A098765432      4       N     ALA   1  48.343 23.545 32.02 1.00 0.00         N
A890765348      5       B     VAL   1  48.343 23.545 32.02 1.00 0.00         B
```

Comment: The challenge is reading a line at a time from two different files.  It would probably be easier you could use a programming language like Perl, C, or Java.  One option with bash is `read -r`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26601/how-to-read-from-two-input-files-using-while-loop

Comment: I see you add the picture because you want to use color to make it easier to understand. But you need at least to post it as text as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: It seems for me that simple change `$1=a[FNR]` => `$1="A"a[FNR]` should help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the first character of column1 (the `A`) in the first file and assuming 
it's okay to use tabs to separate the fields:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
  NR==FNR{ a[FNR]=$1; next }
  { $1=substr($1,1,1) a[FNR] }1
' file2.dat file1.dat > result.dat
```

Comment: Awesome, so much simpler than I thought

Comment: It's not so much different to the original script :)

Comment: Its just printing the second file values alone with concating the first character in the field of file1.

Comment: @HemanthTanna Did you switch the arguments, i.e. `file1.dat file2.dat` instead of `file2.dat file1.dat`?

Comment: To be clear, that's not working `with out changing the file format for each line`, it's replacing all chains of white space in the input with single tab chars. If the output matched the input than it'd be because all white space in the input happened to be individual tab chars but at least some of the sample input text posted such as `48.343 23.545 32.02 1.00 0.00` is clearly blank-separated, not tab-separated.

Comment: Yes, `assuming it's okay to use tabs to separate the fields`.

Comment: That might be a reasonable approach if you also set FS to `\t` because if you do that and all field-separating spaces are `\t`s then no harm done even if there are blanks within fields but if you don't do that and there are blanks in the file (as it looks like from the posted example) then you'd be changing the formatting by setting OFS alone to `\t`.

Comment: @HemanthTanna from [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61444739/is-there-any-shell-script-to-replace-values-of-file1-dat-to-file2-dat-with-out-c#comment108696830_61445616) it sounds like you have carriage returns (`CR` aka `\r` aka `control-M`) in your input, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/45772525/1745001. Swapping the order of the input files wouldn't produce the symptoms you describe but control-Ms would.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU parallel):

```
parallel  echo {=1 's/^(.)\S+/$1$arg[2]/' =} :::: file1 ::::+ file2
```

Join the two input file by using the `::::+` operator and replace the last part of the first field by the file2 argument.

Alternative using cat & sed:

```
cat -n file2 | sed -E 's#\t(.*)#s/[0-9]+/\1/#' | sed -Ef - file1
```

Prepend line numbers to values in file2 and then replace the introduced tab and the following value by a sed command that replaces the first occurrence of multiple integers by that value. This command is piped into a second invocation of sed that acts on file1. The overall result is a sed command that replaces the first number in each line in file1 by the number in the same line in file2.

Answer (score 0):

These will both work with whatever spaces you have in your input as they don't change any of those spaces or make any assumptions about what they are:

```
$ paste file2 file1 | sed 's/\([^\t]*\)\t\(.\)[^[:space:]]*/\2\1/'
A987654321      1      C      HIE   1   48.343 23.545 32.02 1.00 0.00        H
A567890123      3      C      PHE   1   48.343 23.545 32.02 1.00 0.00        C
A098765432      4      N      ALA   1   48.343 23.545 32.02 1.00 0.00        N
A890765348      5      B      VAL   1   48.343 23.545 32.02 1.00 0.00        B
```

or if you prefer an awk solution:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;next} {print substr($0,1,1) a[FNR] substr($0,length($1)+1)}' file2 file1
A987654321      1      C      HIE   1   48.343 23.545 32.02 1.00 0.00        H
A567890123      3      C      PHE   1   48.343 23.545 32.02 1.00 0.00        C
A098765432      4      N      ALA   1   48.343 23.545 32.02 1.00 0.00        N
A890765348      5      B      VAL   1   48.343 23.545 32.02 1.00 0.00        B
```

The problem  you were having is that any time you modify a field (e.g. $1) awk reconstructs the record which, with the default FS and OFS, replaces all contiguous chains of white space with a single blank char. If you modify the record ($0) instead of any specific field that doesn't happen.